Commutator group and conjugacy classes
Let $G$ be a finite solvable group which is not nilpotent, and let $H=[G,G]$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. Does the following hold for $G$ and $H$?
"There exists $g \in G \setminus H$ and $h \neq e \in H$ such that $[h,g]=hgh^{-1}g^{-1}$ is some conjugate ($G$-conjugate) of $h$."
Comment: Since $H$ is the commutator subgroup, it is normal. Therefore, it is union of some conjugacy classes of $G$. However I am not able to make use of this.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

In a nilpotent group, this can never happen.

I guess it just depends on the group, right? In $BS(1,2)$ this does hold, and in $\mathbb{Z}\wr\mathbb{Z}$ it does not hold, so I think there's not really an answer besides, "sometimes yes sometimes no."

Unless I miss something, this might be sensitive on whether the commutator $[a,b]$ is defined as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ or $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$. (There are two more possible definitions but for this question, these boil down to one of these.)

@YCor, re, if we write $[h, g]_1 = h g h^{-1}g^{-1}$ and $[h, g]_2 = g h g^{-1}h^{-1}$ (I have never seen this latter definition—the only other definition I am used to is $[h, g]_3 = h^{-1}g^{-1}h g$—but I trust you that it exists), then $[h, g]_2 = g[h, g^{-1}]_1 g^{-1}$, so I don't think that it can make a difference for the answer to this question.

Note: if the condition $g\notin [G,G]$ is dropped, the condition is equivalent to: there exists a conjugacy class $C\neq{1}$ and $a,b\in C$ such that $ab\in C$.

@Jins Please see the "answer" below.

If $[h,g]=h^k$ (where $h^k=k^{−1}hk$) then $[[h,g],g^k]=[h^k,g^k]=[h,g]^k=h^{k^2}$. Continuing this way, for $n>1$ we have
$$ [h,g,g^k,g^{k^2},\dots,g^{k^{n−1}}]=h^{k^n}, $$
where by convention this expression is bracketed to the left, so for example $[a,b,c]$ denotes $[[a,b],c]$. If $G$ is nilpotent, then for large enough $n$ all such commutators of length at least $n+1$ are the identity, so this shows that $h^{k^n}=1$ and hence $h=1$. It follows that your condition cannot hold for any $g$ and $h\ne 1$ in a nilpotent group.
But note also that your condition fails in most dihedral groups of twice odd order. For example, in the dihedral group $G$ of order $14$, $H$ has order $7$, and if $1\ne h\in H$, $g\in G\setminus H$, then $[h,g]=h^{-2}$ is not conjugate to $h$.

It holds in an elementary abelian $p$-group with a Singer cycle on top, for obvious reasons. This includes cases like $S_3$, $A_4$, $\mathbb{Z}/p\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)$. Maybe this is what led you to think it might be true? In any case, it seems usually to be false.

Isn't it simpler to say "As $h\ne e$ and the group is nilpotent, there exists $n\ge 0$ such that $$h\in\gamma_n(G)\setminus\gamma_{n+1}(G).$$ We have $[h,g]\in\gamma_{n+1}(G)$ which therefore cannot conjugate to $h$ as $\gamma_{n+1}(G)$ is normal."

I dunno, seems like pretty much the same intuition to me. Whatever you find easiest, I suppose.

Note that both proofs generalise to residually nilpotent groups. Does this cover any additionnal solvable group ? (No finite ones as in OP's question unfortunately.)

To spell it out, I'd say the intuition is that commutators go down a central series, conjugations don't.
